# How to add a user input with an output in Javascript react/material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im working on a project and need it to be in react js and material UI. I was wondering how I can implement the code below to fit the format I need which is just a single js file.

```
//js file

function calculate(){
var input1Value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var input2Value = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  
var output1 = parseInt(input1Value) * 4.5;
document.getElementById('output1').value = output1;
  
var output2 = parseInt(output1) + parseInt(input2Value);
document.getElementById('output2').value = output2;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//.HTML file

Input1 : <input type="text" id="input1" value="25000" />
Input2 : <input type="text" id="input2" value="30000" />
<button onClick="calculate();">Calculate</button>

Output1 : <input type="text" id="output1" />
Output2 : <input type="text" id="output2" />
```

Comment: Show your attempt, or you don't know React?

Comment: @Odunsi im new to react so im not too sure on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        input1: 25000,
        input2: 30000,
        output1: '',
        output2: ''
    };

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.calculate = this.calculate.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange1(event) {
    this.setState({input1: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChange2(event) {
    this.setState({input2: event.target.value});
  }

  calculate(event) {
    this.setState({
        output1: parseInt(this.state.input1) * 4.5,
        output2: parseInt(this.state.output1) + parseInt(this.state.input2)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        Input1 : <input type="text" id="input1" value="{this.state.input1}"  onChange={this.handleChange1}/>
        Input2 : <input type="text" id="input2" value="{this.state.input2}"  onChange={this.handleChange2}/>
        <button onClick="{this.calculate}">Calculate</button>

        Output1 : <input type="text" id="{this.state.output1}" />
        Output2 : <input type="text" id="{this.state.output2}" />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: disregard my comment about the error, i have fixed it @Nikita

Comment: Is it possible for you to make it so that the code can show up on a page with a text box and a functional calculate button @Nikita

Comment: how did you start react app?

Comment: the react app compiled fine but the result is not showing up whats so ever @Nikita